# csv Can I quote empty field

Tags: csv

I know I can format csv file like this

"value","va,lue1","val""ue"

Can I quote empty value like this (first value is the empty value)

"", "value1", "value2"

Thanks.

Comment: Why not? I can't see a reason this shouldn't work.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible - empty fields don't get enclosed between quotes - at least not in Excel/OpenOffice/LibreOffice. This way you can't simply import the data as long as you might have the field separator (like the comma) also contained in some field value...